# Have opencv trackbar display time of video

Tags: python, opencv, media-player

I have a simple media player in OpenCV (python). I wanted to show the "time" of the video using a trackbar. First of all, here are the functions I am using to convert a frame number to a time:

```
def _seconds(value, framerate):
    if isinstance(value, str):  # value seems to be a timestamp
        _zip_ft = zip((3600, 60, 1, 1/framerate), value.split(':'))
        return sum(f * float(t) for f,t in _zip_ft)
    elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):  # frames
        return value / framerate
    else:
        return 0

def _timecode(seconds, framerate):
    return '{h:02}:{m:02}:{s:02}' \
            .format(h=int(seconds/3600),
                    m=int(seconds/60%60),
                    s=int(seconds%60))


def _frames(seconds, framerate):
    return seconds * framerate

def timecode_to_frames(timecode, framerate, start=None):
    return _frames(_seconds(timecode, framerate) - _seconds(start, framerate), framerate)

def frames_to_timecode(frames, framerate, start=None):
    return _timecode(_seconds(frames, framerate) + _seconds(start,framerate), framerate)
```

In the end of the day, the return is a string that is of format Hours:Minutes:Seconds.

So... I realize that using a trackbar to do this is probably impossible because definition...

```
 C++: int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange=0, void* userdata=0)

Python: cv.CreateTrackbar(trackbarName, windowName, value, count, onChange) → None
    Parameters: 

        trackbarname – Name of the created trackbar.
        winname – Name of the window that will be used as a parent of the created trackbar.
        value – Optional pointer to an integer variable whose value reflects the position of the slider. Upon creation, the slider position is defined by this variable.
        count – Maximal position of the slider. The minimal position is always 0.
        onChange – Pointer to the function to be called every time the slider changes position. This function should be prototyped as void Foo(int,void*); , where the first parameter is the trackbar position and the second parameter is the user data (see the next parameter). If the callback is the NULL pointer, no callbacks are called, but only value is updated.
        userdata – User data that is passed as is to the callback. It can be used to handle trackbar events without using global variables.
```

...and...

```
Python: cv2.setTrackbarPos(trackbarname, winname, pos) → None

C: void cvSetTrackbarPos(const char* trackbar_name, const char* window_name, int pos)

Python: cv.SetTrackbarPos(trackbarName, windowName, pos) → None
    Parameters: 

        trackbarname – Name of the trackbar.
        winname – Name of the window that is the parent of trackbar.
        pos – New position.
```

...make it very clear that an `int` must be passed to the "pos" and basically everything else.

Do you guys have a solution for this?
Thanks.

Comment: The trackbar of OpenCV is super basic with the GUI options.... and only is allowed to pass int... I would recommend to use another GUI framework like Qt or in your case tkinter

Comment: You can also write the time of the video in the image instead of a trackbar... this can be done with opencv. If you only want to display the time. If you want to also manipulate the time of the video, my previous comment stands

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Scale i.e. slider widget provided in tkinter

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)